# Where is installed lightswitch desktop application

Tags: deployment, clickonce, visual-studio-lightswitch

I'm trying to uninstall, and reinstall a Lightswitch Desktop Application.

The uninstall message is showed to me with sucess, but, when I try to install again, the message

```
'.', hexadecimal value 0x00, is invalid character. Line 1, position 1.
```

is showed to me.

It's strange to me, because in the others clients this message is not showed and the application runs without problems, and it's started after an electrical power failure.

Comment: If it's clickOnce then it will be somewhere under `C:\Users\yourUserName\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft`

Answer (score 0):

CACHE

1. Run start programs lightswitch
2. Go to the last tab and clear the cache
3. Reinstall

PROGRAM

1. Instal/uninstall programs
2. Remove it